# use msgbox to tell how many records have been inserted and updated

Tags: mysql, vba

How do I incorporate a mysql query into a messagebox in vba. What I want to do is when a user  sends data into the database using dgv. How can I get a messagebox to show how many records are going in as updatse and how many are going in as inserts.

FYI I am using on duplicate key update function.

Thanks

Comment: I am fairly new to visual basic, so just wanted to get some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to see a little bit of your code, but you just need to set up a variable represent each element you want to display (say nUpdates and nInserts). Then just display that variable in the message box:

```
MsgBox("Records going in as updates:" & nUpdates & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "Records going in as inserts:" & nInserts)
```